# Unknown field 'state' in domain when editing attribute

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Using Odoo 10 (fetched from GitHub commit [`7413b26`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/7413b2624c6554bf641c2426c45c70fd59bc7490), branch `10.0`), installing a module which I'm porting over from Odoo 8.

This module forces the `purchase.order.line` form to show up upon clicking a line in `purchase.order` by removing the `editable` attribute from the `tree`, but when saving changes done in that form Odoo raises:

> Error: Unknown field state in domain [["state","in",["purchase","to approve","done","cancel"]]]

purchase_order_error.xml:

```xml
<record id="purchase_order_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="33"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="editable"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

The `__manifest__.py` is:

```python
{'name': "purchase_order_error",'depends': ['base', 'product', 'purchase'],'data': ['purchase_order_error.xml',],'installable':True}
```

and `__init__.py` is just the usual `from . import purchase_order_error`.

Here are some more observations:

- The field `state` can have the following Selection values: `[draft]`, `[sent]`, `[to approve]`, `[purchase]`, `[done]`, `[cancel]`; `[draft]` and `[sent]` do not appear in the error.
- An Odoo user [reported same problem](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/15247) on the Odoo GitHub bug tracker, without any solution as the time of writing.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Not sure about the msg error but try change the editable to: <attribute name="editable">bottom</attribute>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when saving the record from the form view
 the state field is not defined. you don't get this error
 in the tree view because the field is there:

```xml
                <page string="Products">
                        <field name="order_line" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'in', ('done', 'cancel'))]}">
                             <tree string="Purchase Order Lines" editable="bottom">
                                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                                <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                                .....
                                ....
                                ..
```

so you need to add it to the embedded form too:

```xml
    <record id="xxx_purchase_order_form_list_details" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">xxx_purchase_order_form_list_details</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="editable"/>
            </xpath>

             <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//form//field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
                <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```xml
<record id="purchase_order_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="33"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="editable">top</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

> In your case it's going to open form view to allow you to create
>   records, because you have not given the value of editable attribute.

So in form view of purchase order line there might be no field defined "state". According to rule if fields are used anywhere in attrs, domains then it must be defined on view, it doesn't matter you can define it invisible.

So just add this field in Purchase order line form view or follow the first solution for `editable="top"`

```xml
<field name="state" invisible="1" />
```